# Year and Month Compare in best way

Tags: c#

i have written this logic to compare Source Year/Month with response year/Month. but i want to write it in better way.  if source year/month is greater than or equal to response year/month then pass.
any suggestion??

```
if (source?.Year == response?.Year)
{
    return source?.Month >= response?.Month
        ? Outcome.Pass()
        : Outcome.Fail();
}
else if (source?.Year < response?.Year)
{
    return Outcome.Fail();
}
else if (source?.Year > response?.Year)
{
    return Outcome.Pass();
}
else
{
    return Outcome.Fail();
}
```

Comment: You can create date time instance and compare it

Comment: You might consider doing `null` checks ahead of time by returning right away if `source` and/or `response` are `null`, because any greater-than/less-than comparison will return false (i.e. `>=` will return `false` even though `==` will return `true` if both are `null`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to compare `source` to the beginning of the `response` month.

```
var responseMonthBegin = response.HasValue 
    ? new DateTime(response.Value.Year, response.Value.Month, 1)
    : (DateTime?)null;

return source >= responseMonthBegin ? Outcome.Pass() : OutCome.Fail();
```

Comment: Congratulations on earning [the Jon Skeet badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9153/348196) :-D

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't think I posted a better answer, just one that got accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Just truncate each to the start of the month:

```
private static DateTime TruncateToMonth(DateTime date) =>
    new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then you can use:

```
// TODO: Null handling
return TruncateToMonth(source) >= TruncateToMonth(response)
    ? Outcome.Pass()
    : Outcome.Fail();
```

Note the TODO there - I haven't tried to handle null values at all. I can never remember the rules clearly enough to predict what your *current* code would do. If I can't figure it out without concentrating, chances are the same would apply for anyone else trying to read the code too :) So I'd make it really explicit how you want nulls to be handled, e.g.

```
return source == null || response == null ? Outcome.Fail()
    : TruncateToMonth(source.Value) >= TruncateToMonth(response.Value) ? Outcome.Pass()
    : Outcome.Fail();
```

As noted in comments, you don't strictly need to truncate the source value - I just find it clearer to read if you do.

Comment: Technically you don't need to truncate the source.

Comment: Also since they do `source?.Month >= response?.Month` if both are null that would be false and result in `OutCome.Fail()`

Comment: @juharr: Yes, I worked out the "no need to truncate source" after looking at your answer - although I'd argue it's clearer to truncate both. Will fix the null bit. (This is exactly the kind of reason I'm saying it should be explicit!)

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea especially if the requirement changes from `>=` to just `>`.